# Replacement for moveLayer in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, update, migration

I am a novice to QGIS tasked with updating other developers' plugins from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3.

Here's the code I need to replace:

```
legend = self.iface.legendInterface()        
index = legend.addGroup('Quadrant Shapes', False)        
self.quad_group = index
self.iface.mapCanvas().setRenderFlag(False)
mlr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
```

According to [GitHub](https://github.com/JonathanWillitts/common-qgis-2-to-3-plugin-fixes), `iface.legendInterface()` has been replaced with `iface.layerTreeView()`, so I can replace the first line with `legend = self.iface.layerTreeView()` but the next line fails because the QgsLayerTreeView object does not have an `addGroup()` attribute.

The general idea is to add a group to the interface and then append some layers to it.

UPDATE:

With the input from Fran Raga and the discovery that moveLayer() is no longer available, the following solution worked for me:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
self.quad_group = root.addGroup('Quadrant Shapes')

self.north_layer = QgsVectorLayer([shp], "North_Quad", "ogr")
self.quad_group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(self.north_layer))

self.south_layer = QgsVectorLayer(os.path.join([shp], "South_Quad", "ogr")
self.quad_group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(self.south_layer))
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For add new Group:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup("Quadrant Shapes")
```

And after add layer to this group:

```
layer =QgsVectorLayer(r"path_shp", "Layer Name", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(layer))
```

Comment: Thanks Fran.  This gets me part of the way through the issue, but I am adding several layers to the group, and I will need to refer to those layers later in the code, so I will need to create variables to hold the layers, then add them collectively to the group.

Comment: For example:  
    `self.north_layer = QgsVectorLayer([shp file], "North_Quad", "ogr")  
     self.south_layer = QgsVectorLayer([shp file], "South_Quad", "ogr")  
...etc.
     QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([self.north_layer, self.south_layer, etc.`  
Next I need to add those layers to the group.

Comment: With moveLayers() gone, layers cannot be moved, only cloned and the original deleted, so the layer must be created within the destination group if it the layer is to be referred to later. Problem resolved with a modification to my code:  

        `self.north_layer = QgsVectorLayer(os.path.join([shp file], "North_Quad", "ogr")  

        self.quad_group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(self.north_layer))
        self.south_layer = QgsVectorLayer([shp file]), "South_Quad", "ogr")  

        self.quad_group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(self.south_layer))  
    etc`

Comment: Update your question then

Comment: Update posted, @fran_raga.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Accept it as an answer if it solved your problem